# how to create views for all table with all name

Tags: database

I need to create views for all tables in database but with column names 
like :

```
create view viewname as select col1, col2 from table name
```

this view should be created for all db tables

Comment: What database server are you using? What have you tried yourself? A generic answer could involve `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but even this greatly depends on what you're using.

Comment: required here to write the generic query which return the script of create views for all table in database with column names instead of select * from table.

Comment: select 'create view'+'vw_'table_name+ 'AS select * from'+table_name from information_schema -  This is am creating but I just want that instead of * i need column names for each table

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` should be of use, then.